# Is it OK to bunnyhop on a Kona/Fastrax AF2 while in Lockout Mode?

Tags: suspension, lock, full-suspension, shocks

I recently got a Kona Tanuki 2012 bike that sports a Kona/Fastrax AF2 Rear Shock. Sometimes while on the road I miss bunnyhopping over things.

Is it wise to lockout the Kona/Fastrax AF2 Rear Shock and bunnyhop like i just don't care? :)
If i over do it, something is going to break?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See my answer to this question for a similar answer:

[Does ProPedal on FOX RP2 rear shock wear out when on during downhill?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/17061/does-propedal-on-fox-rp2-rear-shock-wear-out-when-on-during-downhill/17067#17067)

Basically, you *could* cause damage to the shock by supplying pressure to either the oil or a part that wasn't meant to handle that much force. Now, do I think it'll break after 10 bunnyhops? Probably not, but it could cause much faster wear on the parts involved inside the shock. Also, are you bunnyhopping like a trials rider going 5 or 6 ft in the air? That's a lot more abuse than hopping 4" over that pothole in the road.

So, the bottom line is no, but probably someday. But then again, that's how you'll break anything...repeated abuse!