# Lockout Lego on after going down a flight of stairs

Tags: suspension, damage, lockout

I recently was biking on some roads with my Specialized Pitch Sport 2015 MTB when I found a dirt trail, and forgot to shut off my lockout. I did a bit of hopping on my suspension, but the path was relatively smooth. I only realised after riding down a staircase that my suspension was locked.

Did I damage my suspension by going down the staircase, hopping on the suspension or going 30 mph on somewhat smooth asphalt?

FYI the fork is a Sr suntour xct modified by Specialized and I weigh 100 pounds.

Comment: Welcome to SE.  Please consider browsing through our Tour, which is under the Help menu.  If you have further information to add, use the Edit link which is below your question.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/17061/ or http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/17045/

Answer (score 1):

It is highly unlikely that you have damaged your suspension.  At worst you may have shortened its life by some small and immeasurable amount.

As long as it functions okay now, all you need to do is remember to service it at the appropriate interval.

You can't possibly damage locked-out suspension by riding on flat smooth road because that's exactly what its designed for.    Hopping and stairs would be the cause of any damage.